# Slide orientation in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, orientation

How do I change the orientation of a single slide in a PowerPoint presentation from portrait to landscape?  I do not want my whole presentation to be in landscape.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have the presentation with a mix of both. You can create separate ppt files and call each slide from the other in the orientation that you want them in. But you cannot have both in the same presentation.

Answer (score 1):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/use-portrait-and-landscape-orientation-in-the-same-presentation-HP005194945.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001129491

By default, Microsoft PowerPoint slide layouts are set up in landscape slide orientation. PowerPoint supports either landscape orientation or portrait orientation in a single presentation, but does not support both orientations in the same presentation.

If you want to show portrait-oriented slides during a landscape-oriented presentation, you can link two presentations, giving the effect of one presentation that contains slides of both orientations.

It is best to place both files in the same folder before creating links. That way, if the folder is copied to a CD or moved, the files will still link correctly.